# When is the probability measure in de Finetti's theorem finitely supported?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

Let $(X_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be an exchangeable infinite sequence of random variables taking values in $\{0,1\}$. [De Finetti's theorem](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Esabatti/Stat370/synthese.pdf) states that there exists a unique probability measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ such that for any fixed sequence $(e_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ taking values in $\{0,1\}$ it holds that
$$\Pr(X_1=e_1,\dots,X_n=e_n) = \int_0^1 p^k(1-p)^{n-k} d\mu(p),\tag{1}$$
where $k = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i$.

Thus, for each $n$, the distribution of $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$ is a (possibly infinite) mixture of independent Bernoulli trials.

**Question:** Under what conditions on $(X_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ does $\mu$ have finite support?

That is, when does there exist $m\in \mathbb N$, $p_1,\dots,p_m\in [0,1]$ and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m \ge 0$ with $\sum_{j=1}^m \alpha_j = 1$ such that for any fixed sequence $(e_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ taking values in $\{0,1\}$:
$$\Pr(X_1=e_1,\dots,X_n=e_n) = \sum_{j=1}^m p_j^k(1-p_j)^{n-k} \alpha_j,\tag{2}$$
where $k = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i$?